# C++ code - Coverity (or some other static code analyzer) + thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-analysis, coverity

I was wondering today about the following: is there any tool or extension (for coverity or for other code analyzer), where I can do the following?:

- First, I would set a set of rules, that which codes are generating new threads, so the analyzer knows, that the code will run other thread.
- The tool must follow, which code parts are in which threads, are they in the same, or in different ones.
- I could set "rules", what kind of codes are ensuring me thread safety: for example a MYLOCK class is locking between threads.
- And the reason for the previous 3: the tool should show me warnings, which codes are most likely called by different threads and doesn't have thread-safety usage in it.

Thanks

Comment: Coverity is able to do so IIRC.

Comment: There is no tool that is very good at this or that catches everything, although some langs such as rust have thread safety enforced at the compiler level

Comment: Finding thread-safety problems with a *static* tools seems an immensely hard task to me (but please prove me wrong!). Perhaps you should use a *dynamic* tool like http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html ?

Comment: I'll read it through, we also have valgrind on our project, but I was not totally aware of its feature-set. És köszönöm szépen :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Intel Inspector (also known as Thread Checker). It is dynamic analysis, not static. As far as I remember, it allowed some annotation/instrumentation for custom locks, threading libs in general.